# Eclipse - setting to compiler 1.6 to avoid @Override errors not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm currently developing a small test project with Android and I get the infamous @Override error:

> The method onBackPress() of type KvizActivity must override or implement a
>   supertype method.

Here is the code that causes it:

```
public class KvizActivity extends Activity {
    /** onCreate(), onDestroy(), etc... */

    @Override
    public void onBackPress() {

    }
}
```

Now I know what you are thinking: there are tons of such questions and answers to them already. I know, I read all of them, still, I can't get rid of it. I know the core cause of it is that Eclipse is using JDK 1.5 instead of 1.6 or higher.

But I have done all this: Went to **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Java Compiler** and I set it to **1.6**. Error still there.

Then I went to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java Compiler** and set it to **1.6** there, so it would be global, still it persists. Then I set the **Project Specific Settings** even though I already did this, I retried it. Nothing. I **Cleaned** the project and used **Rebuild** but still it is there.

I cant think of anything else to do.

Here is my Java version:

```
Java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have Eclipse **3.7.1** which I believe is the latest.

I hope anybody can shed some light on this.

Comment: What are the signatures in Activity?  Is there onBackPress() there to override?

Comment: IT IS `public void onBackPressed()` AND NOT `public void onBackPress()`

Comment: SO STUPID. Thank you, its the most obvious things that I always miss!

Comment: @vanneto what makes us humans are these sort of things!!! hehe

Comment: @vanneto Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you want to override is `onBackPressed()`.  For `@Override` to work, the method signature must match the method declared in the parent class.  In this case, you misspelled the method name.